# How to create variable in javascript from two other variables - create chart using chartnew.js

Tags: javascript, c#, chartnew.js

I want to display a stacked chart using chartnew.js in aspx page . I got all relevant data from webmethods. The data for chart is in the format

```
var classdata = {
                    labels: ["English", "French", "Science", "Maths", "SS", "IT","Computer","Arts"],
                    datasets: [

                        {
                            data: [3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 4, 9],
                            fillColor: "#B1CD4F",
                            title: "EXCELLENT"
                        }, {
                            data: [5, 2, 10, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2],
                            fillColor: "#4663EA",
                            title: "FAIR"
                        }, {
                            data: [6, 5, 4, 4, 0, 7, 4, 2],
                            fillColor: "#B812E0",
                            title: "GOOD"
                        }, {
                            data: [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                            fillColor: "#4173D1",
                            title: "NEEDS IMPROVEMENT"
                        }, {
                            data: [2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                            fillColor: "#55E949",
                            title: "SATISFACTORY"
                        }, {
                            data: [7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 3, 10, 7],
                            fillColor: "#4DD1E7",
                            title: "VERY GOOD"
                        }]
                }
```

I got all these data from two webmethods. I took it in two separate variables. That is the labels values to a variable named "datalables" and the dataset values to variable named "data".

Now i want to combine these two variables and create the data for chart. I tried like the following, but it is not working ie the chart is not displaying.

`var classdata = {labels: [datalabels],
                  datasets: [data]
                 };`

How can i combine these two variables to make the chart? Someone please help.

The complete code is here.

```
function LoadClassChart() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home.aspx/GetClassChart",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Grade: $('select[id$=BatchDropDownList1]').val(), Term: $('select[id$=TermDropDownList1]').val() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                $(".classdivstyle").css("backgroundImage", "url(/Images/back.png)");

                var data;
                try {
                    data = r.d;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
                        alert(e.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        throw (e);
                    }
                }
                var el = document.getElementById("<%= classcanvas.ClientID %>");
                var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

                var classdata = {
                    labels: [datalabels],
                    datasets: [data]
                };

                var newopts = {
                    inGraphDataShow: true,
                    inGraphDataFontColor: 'white',
                    inGraphDataFontSize: 14,
                    inGraphDataFontStyle: 'bold',
                    highLight: true,
                    highLightSet: { fillColor: "red", inGraphDataFontColor: "black", inGraphDataFontSize: 18 },
                    highLightFullLine: true,
                    datasetFill: true,
                    scaleFontSize: 16,
                    canvasBorders: true,
                    graphTitle: $('select[id$=TermDropDownList1]').val() + " Performance",
                    graphTitleFontFamily: "'Segoe UI'",
                    graphTitleFontSize: 22,
                    graphTitleFontColor: "#666",
                    graphSubTitle: "Class Teacher : ",
                    legend: true,
                    yAxisLabel: "Students",
                    xAxisLabel: "Subjects",
                    yAxisUnit: "Nos.",
                    annotateDisplay: true,
                    dynamicDisplay: true
                }
                $(".classdivstyle").css("backgroundImage", "none");
                var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(classdata, newopts);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('There was an error in loading chart.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: try removing  square brackets in "classdata" object

Comment: `labels: [datalabels]` means an array with one member "datalabels", so try Damitha's comment.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code, but the chart is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

remove square brackets in classdata variable as follows

var classdata = {
                    labels: datalabels,
                    datasets: data
                };

I'm guessing datalabels and data are returning as an arrays.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code, but the chart is not displaying.

Comment: can you post the content of r.d in data = r.d; :)

Comment: This is the value in r.d -  `{fillColor : "#A6DD4A",strokeColor : "#979491",data : [12,8,4,1,13,11],title: "EXCELLENT"},{fillColor : "#E3D954",strokeColor : "#CEDC51",data : [6,2,4,6,0,4],title: "FAIR"},{fillColor : "#364C06",strokeColor : "#C90DA8",data : [2,5,7,9,1,2],title: "GOOD"},{fillColor : "#68F351",strokeColor : "#CAA55D",data : [0,0,0,1,0,1],title: "NEEDS IMPROVEMENT"},{fillColor : "#ED585E",strokeColor : "#D59EAC",data : [3,8,8,6,9,5],title: "VERY GOOD"}`

Comment: where is datalabels variable defined, is it accessible in ajax success

Comment: it is outside of all the functions, i can see the values of datalabels when i do `alert(datalabels)`

Comment: When i put the values directly in a variable like this it is working `var classdata = {
labels: ["en", "fr", "hi", "mar", "math", "sc"],
datasets: [
{ fillColor: "#A6DD4A", strokeColor: "#979491", data: [12, 8, 4, 1, 13, 11], title: "EXCELLENT" },
{ fillColor: "#E3D954", strokeColor: "#CEDC51", data: [6, 2, 4, 6, 0, 4], title: "FAIR" },
{ fillColor: "#364C06", strokeColor: "#C90DA8", data: [2, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2], title: "GOOD" },
{ fillColor: "#68F351", strokeColor: "#CAA55D", data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], title: "NEEDS IMPROVEMENT" }
]
}`

Comment: try this darasers:JSON.parse(data)

Comment: do it like this, var data1 = JSON.parse(data); then add this to darasers:data1. because sometime js get confused when creating a object and we convert properties inside.

Comment: i got exception on parse - Unexpected tocken f in JSON at position 1.  what is wrong in this data? {fillColor : "#8907B7",strokeColor : "#D028CD",data : [11,8,6,1,10,3],title: "EXCELLENT"},
{fillColor : "#C41C8F",strokeColor : "#984C1E",data : [0,3,0,8,3,3],title: "FAIR"}

Comment: are you returning the data as a array? I guess this is the problem. to be valid json it should be look like following. [{fillColor : "#A6DD4A",strokeColor : "#979491",data : [12,8,4,1,13,11],title: "EXCELLENT"},{fillColor : "#E3D954",strokeColor : "#CEDC51",data : [6,2,4,6,0,4],title: "FAIR"},{fillColor : "#364C06",strokeColor : "#C90DA8",data : [2,5,7,9,1,2],title: "GOOD"},{fillColor : "#68F351",strokeColor : "#CAA55D",data : [0,0,0,1,0,1],title: "NEEDS IMPROVEMENT"},{fillColor : "#ED585E",strokeColor : "#D59EAC",data : [3,8,8,6,9,5],title: "VERY GOOD"}]. you are missing [] around json array.

Comment: [] is also there. i merged the two variables from the cs code and now it is like `labels: ["label1","label2",...], datasets: [ ... dataset values ...]` now how do i use it to create the chart? i tried  `var classdata =r.d; var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(classdata, newopts);` still no chart is displaying